# Fourier series and evaluation of another series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I was given to expand in a Fourier series the function $f(x)=|x|, \; x \in [-\pi, \pi]$.
The Fourier series is quite known and I had done the calculations and I ended up to the formula:

$$f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}+2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n -1}{\pi n^2}\cos n x$$

which is  correct. Now the exercise wants me to evaluate the series:
$$ \sum_{n={\rm odd} \geq 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

What value should I insert in the Fourier? Plugging $x=0$ I get another series , that is I get $\zeta(2)$. For the series I want , the value i should plug in is still is a mystery to me.

Comment: Unless, we take for granted that $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6 = 3/4 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$ and the result follows from there.

I cannot see something else right now. Am I overseening things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have:
$$ |x| = \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\cos((2n+1)x)}{(2n+1)^2}\tag{1}$$
by setting $x=0$ it follows that:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: The Fourier series I got above is correct. Jack would you mind explaining how you got that? It is not that clear to me.. @Essam I do not see something wrong in Jack's Fourier Series..(since he produces what we want) but I don't follow him (for the moment)

Comment: @Tolaso can you plot it to check it?

Comment: @Essam I crosschecked my answer with that of the link: https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090904165050AAN43Qt 

(Sorry I do not know how to introduce a URL in a comment)

Comment: @Jack D' Aurizio: Actually I did. You just manipulated the series. Duh, I was overseeing things.